# How would you render the first n models from a collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a parent view that fetches a collection of 20 models from the server. The parent view then calls on three subviews to render. Each of these child views uses the collection but all to a different degree. For instance, one will use all the models, while the other two will only need the first 5 models to render initially. I would like to pass a collection of the first five models to the two childviews that only need five, and pass the full collection to the view that uses all of them.

I could render them all separately and make three different calls to the server, but 1 call is better than 3 and I was wondering if there is a way to do this with only call.

I've tried the underscore method
    `_.first(this.collection.models, 5)` but when you pass this result to the view as :

`this.view = new View({collection:_.first(this.collection.models, 5) })` I get an error

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can have multiple views referencing the same collection, so instead of trying to pass part of the collection to each view you might just want to have it's render logic only render the models you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method [collection.first](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) but this method returns array of models. So you need to create new Collection from it:

```
var firstFive = new Backbone.Collection(fullCollection.first(5));
```